# Recognizing mouse click events in matplolib with qt backend

Tags: python, qt, matplotlib

While using matplotlib with qt as the backend in a jupyter notebook, the window typically looks like this.

[image: Qt window]

I wonder if it is possible to recognize mouse click events. For example clicking on the axis should open the "axes" settings and clicking anywhere within the axes of the plot/subplot should open the "curves" settings of that particular plot/subplot. These settings can actually be accessed from the toolbar above. But is it possible to do the same with a mouse click?

Comment: The tasks like recognizing some action of the mouse on the canvas (for example if I press any element) do not depend on the backend but on matplotlib so Qt cannot and should not do it. To give you an idea: matplotlib creates an image based on the instructions and then Qt displays that image so Qt cannot recognize (nor does it know) that it is an axes